# Ajax form doesn't submits data to php on first click but submits on second click

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form that submits through ajax. At first click it sends the request to php but doesnt send post variables and however when i submit form for second or third time it submits the form and gets the success response. The ajax request doesn't fail on first click it just doesnt send data to php.When i check the network tab request fields show up there on the first click and have correct values but doesnt reach php. Here is my code

```js
jQuery("#bidding-form").on('submit', function(e) {
    var request_english_level = jQuery('#request_english_level').val();
    var job_title = jQuery('#job_title').val();
    var request_type = jQuery('#request_type').val();
    var estimated_hours = jQuery('#estimated_hours').val();
    var designation = jQuery('#designation').val();
    var service_type = jQuery('#service_type').val();
    var budget = jQuery("#budget").val();
    var user_id = jQuery('#user_id').val();
    var locations = jQuery('#location').val();
    var payment_terms = jQuery('#payment_terms').val();
    var application_no = jQuery('#application_no').val();
    var deadline_apply = jQuery('#deadline_apply').val();
    var close_date = jQuery('#close_date').val();
    var delivery_deadline = jQuery('#delivery_deadline').val();
    var experience = jQuery('#consultant_experience').val();
    var description = jQuery('#request_description').val();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    var length = jQuery(".attachment")[0].files.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        formdata.append('file[]', jQuery(".attachment")[0].files[i]);
    }
    formdata.append('action', 'save_bid_info');
    var checked_skills = []
    jQuery("input[name='request_skills[]']:checked").each(function() {
        //checked_skills.push(parseInt(jQuery(this).val()));
        formdata.append('request_skills[]', parseInt(jQuery(this).val()));
    });
    var languages = []
    jQuery("input[name='languages[]']:checked").each(function() {
        //languages.push(parseInt(jQuery(this).val()));
        formdata.append('languages[]', parseInt(jQuery(this).val()));
    });
    formdata.append('designation', designation);
    //  formdata.append('request_skills', checked_skills);
    formdata.append('request_type', request_type);
    formdata.append('estimated_hours', estimated_hours);
    formdata.append('service_type', service_type);
    formdata.append('delivery_deadline', delivery_deadline);
    formdata.append('job_title', job_title);
    formdata.append('locations', locations);
    formdata.append('request_type', request_type);
    formdata.append('payment_terms', payment_terms);
    formdata.append('application_no', application_no);
    formdata.append('deadline_apply', deadline_apply);
    formdata.append('close_date', close_date);
    formdata.append('experience', experience);
    formdata.append('description', description);
    formdata.append('budget', budget);
    //  formdata.append('languages', languages);
    formdata.append('request_english_level', request_english_level);
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajax_url,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formdata,
            beforeSend: function() {
                jQuery(".loader").show();
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                jQuery('.loader').hide();
            }
        })
        .done(function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (response.success == true) {
                jQuery(".ajax-processor").hide();
            } else {
                jQuery(".ajax-processor").find('p').html(response.msg);
            }
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        })
});
```

```
// PHP CODE
if(isset($_POST['budget']) && !empty($_POST['budget']))
{
   // on second click this is executed
}
else
{
  // on first click this is executed
}
```

Comment: @KenLee dataType specifies what type of response you expect back from the server, not what you are sending.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to print out the `$_POST` (print_r() or var_dump()) array to see what it contains.

Comment: Remove the `contentType: false` or set it to `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`. multipart/form-data is the content type of the formData object when you send it.

Comment: If all the fields are part of the form that is submitted you can just create the formData object based on the form: `var formdata = new FormData(e.target);` instead of defining all fields as variables and then add them to the formData object.